# On impulsive optimal control with functions of not bounded variation

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I have the following optimal control problem
$$
J=\int_0^TF(t,y_1(t),y_2(t))dt \to \min,
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
  &\dot y_1(t) = f(t,y_1(t),y_2(t)) + g(t)\nu(t),\\
  &\dot y_2(t) = \nu(t),
\end{align}
where $\nu$ is an impulsive control, and $y_i$ are phase coordinates. Results on necessary conditions (maximum principle) of this type of problems which I've seen require functions $f$ and $g$ be smooth in $t$. But in my case both of them have unbounded variation in $t$ in any interval (trajectory of Brownian motion as a particular case).

So how this problem can be solved and are there any result on this type of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is interested, there is a paper by Arutyunov, Karamzin and Pereira, "Pontryagin’s maximum principle for constrained impulsive control problems", which presents a version of maximum principle for problems with non-smooth data. Here is a [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X11002513) for it on ScineceDirect.